# Set Bonus VS iLevel & Raw Stats

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When you have 2 or 4 (or all) of the *Set Pieces* of a *Tier* of *PvE Gear*, you get a *Set Bonus*, which could include some spells doing more damage, or having their *cooldowns* reset, etc.

### My question:

Is there an average or standard/generic case of when the *Set Bonus* is inferior to a higher item level or other raw stats?

For instance, when you have 4/5 *Set Pieces*, and you pick up a new Chest piece, 8 *Item Levels* higher than the Chest piece from the *Tier Set* you currently have on, should you replace it?

Comment: A bit hard to answer.  It depends on your spec, the specific set bonus, and the secondary stats on your tier chest.  Some bonuses are more powerful than getting gear from the next tier and some bonuses are weak enough to be almost worthless.  You may want to check with a class theorycrafter for a more precise answer for your situation.

Comment: The fact that there is no generic/standard/average margin (as in 8 item levels is better than set bonus) is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I can Recommend [SimCraft](http://simulationcraft.org/) to find out about whether something is better or worse. You can download it and customize the simulation. A really great tool for accurate calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique answer to your question :

> When is the Set Bonus inferior to a higher item level or other raw
>   stats?

The thing is this is case specific, sometimes you will have to take the new piece, sometimes you will have to keep your old set a little longer. The Set Bonus is inferior to a higher item level when in total you get more advantage from your new item than from your older set, but to know that you need to make some theorycrafting, or you need to show us a concrete example.

So the only answer for you general question is :
if you get more advantage from the new piece than from your set, replace, if not, keep your set. And I say "advantage" because it can be totally different bonuses, so it can be about stats or gameplay if the new stats are good in another way.